# Issue when "fixed" stream manipulator is removed

Tags: c++, stream

I am new to C++, learning it by my self, and I am using the book "C++ how to program - 7th edition" from Deitel. Now, please have a look at the following code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cmath>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        double principle = 1000;
        double amount;
        double rate = 0.05;

        cout << "Year" << setw(21) << "Amount on deposit" << endl;

        cout << fixed << setprecision(2);

        for(int years=1; years<=10; years++)
        {
            amount = principle * pow(1.0+rate,1.0);

            cout << setw(4) << years << setw(21) << amount << endl;
        }
}
```

When I removed the "fixed" stream manipulator, the output becomes stupid, which means, just ascii letters and numbers. When I insert it, the output comes without any problem. My question is, why is this happening? Is "fixed" mandatory for all the programs which has "double" type outputs? Please help.

And another thing. What are stream manipulators? As a Java developer, I thought these might be some kind of constant variables, but it is not! They are methods? Then why the brackets are not there? Please answer to this question too.

Thanks

Comment: manipulators are functions.  The tricky bit is you aren't calling the functions and sending the results to the stream, you're literally sending the functions _themselves_ to the stream (That's why no parenthesis).  The stream recognizes the type of the function, and then calls the function giving itself as a parameter.  the `setw` function then modifies the stream's width.  The reason they do this is because you could write a new function no one has ever seen before and simply use it.  That wouldn't be possible with enumerations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output does not "become stupid": you simply let your output stream choose the format for your floating-point numbers, and it picks scientific notation. This gives you `1e+03` (which means `1*10^3`) instead of `1050.00`. The use of `fixed` tells the stream that you do not want scientific notation; you could also use [`scientific`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/scientific/) to force the scientific format. Since the precise format depends depends on your application requirements, the choice to use `fixed` or `scientific` is ultimately up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Manipulators like fixed are functions, but if you wanted the common () for it then it would look like this:

fixed(cout); //Instead of using the << or >> you pass the stream into the manipulator function.

See this reference for more on manipulators:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/

Also, fixed documentation can be found here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks you for the reply. Seems like lot of stuff are out there!

Answer (score 0):

It's not just ascii letter and numbers

1e+03 is scientific writing for 1*10^3 which is 1000

for reference:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/

Answer (score 0):

If you had chose a wider precision, your output would have been different without `fixed`.

```
        cout << setprecision(6); // 6 instead of 2
```

Then your output would have looked more like you expected. (Incidentally, you should compute the compound interest by folding the interest earned back into the principle.)

Otherwise, with only `setprecision(2)`, the formatter decides to use scientific notation in order to only display 2 digits of precision.

But, since you want the output to provide a fixed number of digits, what you have provided (both `fixed` and `setprecision(2)`) will do that.